# How_Can i make Versions in Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

While running a job in jenkins using ant script i got the build in artifactory . My problem is when a change in build happens it should store as a new version in artifactory. How can i do this?

Thank You

Comment: How you are handling the versions at the moment? for instance the first one

Comment: while running jobs in jenkins it should automatically create versions in artifactory. this is my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is missing a lot of details, but assuming you are using a Jenkinsfile together with the Artifactory Jenkins plugin, you would need to use something like `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` when defining the `target` in the Jenkinsfile.

It should be something similar to:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "my-build-directory/*.tar.gz",
      "target": "my-repo/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/"
    }
  ]
}
```

If this helps answer your question, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as the accepted answer.